# How to start learning server side coding in sharepoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint-2013

I am not able to understand where to start from and what examples to do for learning SharePoint server side coding.

Please help me with this.

Comment: You should start from [Google](http://google.com)

Comment: I am searching on google but for server side coding I am confused because there are different things related to C# coding in sharepoint..

Comment: if so, it will be better to ask what you confused, because you question  looks  too broad.

Answer (score 0):

Plural Sight is usually the first place I'm checking for learning something new. If you dont like it, google it up and good luck
https://app.pluralsight.com/library/courses/sharepoint-2013-fundamentals/table-of-contents

Comment: is this resouce free ?

Comment: you get 10 days free trial, and then you have to pay. 10 days suppose to be enough for several of their courses. Personally, i pay them since i think its good value for money, but this is because that websites suits me.